# ¿error al hacer una consulta para que no se me repitan los datos

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenos dias estoy haciendo un sistema el cual en un select aparecen unas cedulas y llenos unas preguntas y con un boton mando el dato pero quiero que no se repita muchas veces el dato al dar el boton enviar y me salio este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es la linea 45? el error dice que el error lo tienes en al linea 45, si puedes colocar o cambiar la imagen donde indique dicha linea por favor

Comment: Listo amigo ya la pude corregir

Comment: no uses imágenes para poner el código, no es nada legible, pégalo como texto y dale formato

Comment: a ok gracias por la recomendacion hermano ya no la puedo eliminar ya me la eliminaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema va que en tu sentencia SQL deberia ser asi

```
SELECT * FROM tecnico_incumplimientos WHERE id_tecnicos = '".$Resultados_tec[0]['id_tecnicos']."' AND id_pregunta = '".$tec_inc_id_pregunta."'
```

y lo otro que va hay ya que solo le estas poniendo restriccion a la pregunta